# returning value from a function in middleware in laravel

Tags: laravel

i've a function in my admin model which has connected to role model by many to many relationship. i created a middleware to check the roles of admins and redirect them  to their dashboard, but i'm not sure it is returning the correct value. here is the way i'm checking -> `Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role()`. i mean the `role()` method is returning the `role_id` but how to check it ? like `Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role()->role_id == 1`, though this is not a correct way

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in your `User`(or `Admin` whichever is authenticatable) Model :

```
<?php 

public function hasRoles(array $roles)
{
    return $this->roles()->whereIn('role_id', [$roles])->exists();
}

// Then you can check using ids
const ADMIN_ROLE = 1;
const OTHER_ROLE = 2;

if(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRoles([self::ADMIN_ROLE, self::OTHER_ROLE])){
// Current user is either admin or other role
}
```

If you have name of a role then you can use that instead of ids as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the better way.

In user model, write a function something like this .

```
public function hasRole( ... $roles ) {
   foreach ($roles as $role) {
      if ($this->roles->contains('column_name', $role)) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

in middleware, you'd write something like this

```
if(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRole("admin", "moderator)){
   return $next($request);
}
```

This way you'd not check for ids , because ids might change.

Comment: it is showing "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: my function -> public function hasRole($roles) {
       foreach ($roles as $role) {
          if ($this->role->contains('role_id', $role)) {
             return true;
          }
       }
       return false;
    }